# Statistical test for comparing two distributions

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions, statistical-inference, hypothesis-testing

I am observing a phenomena, to simplify it, we say the acceleration of objects, $Oi$, for which I measure the acceleration over the time with a frequency of $100$HZ.

Let's imagine I did $50$ experiments, producing $50$ datasets. A dataset, $Di$, contains the acceleration of the object $Oi$ over the time e.g. $2$ seconds.
For each dataset $Di$, I can calculate the Mean, $M_i$, and the Standard Deviation, $SDi$. Therefore, each object can be described with $Oi(M_i,SDi)$

Moreover, I compute the combined mean as in the following:

1) The Combined Mean :
   $Mc= Sum(N_i*M_i)/Sum(N_i)$ where $N_i$ is the cardinality of the dataset $D_i$, per $i=1.50$

2) The Combined standard deviation, $SDc$.
\begin{align}
  \text{Deviance} &= \sum_{i=1}^g n-1_i s_i^2 + \sum_{i=1}^g n_i
  (\bar{x_i} - \bar{x})^2 \\
  \text{SD} &= \sqrt{\frac{1}{N_{\text{total}}-1}\: \text{deviance}}
\end{align}
The result of the above computation is to build a acceleration model $F$ which can be described with the combined mean $Mc$ and combined $SDc$, $F(Mc, SDc)$.

I would like to build a filter that uses $F(Mc,SDc)$ as a model to select those experiments among others that have a complete different distribution and therefore, mean and standard deviation.

The first question is: What is the best statistical test to apply in order to compare $F(Mc,SDc)$ and $O(Mj, SDj)$?
The second question is: How I should phrase the Null Hypthesis and the Alternative Hypothesis?
Additional info: $F(Mc,SDc)$ can be approximate to a Gaussian but for the others, $O(Mj, SDj)$, no info.

Please any help on this would be very appreciated.

Best Regards,
Carlo

Comment: Perhaps better asked on stats.stackexchange.com (and deleted here).

Comment: Thanks Ethan. How Can I delete it from here?

Comment: @EthanBolker We do have a ([tag:hypothesis-testing]) tag on Math.SE.

Comment: Please do [not use pictures for critical portions](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/20529/290189)
of your post. Pictures may not be legible,
cannot be searched and are not view-able to some,
such as those who use screen readers.
I have [edit]ed your question to reflect this principle.  It is
possible that I unintentionally changed the meaning of your question.
Please proofread the question to ensure this has not happened.

Comment: @GNU Supporter: Many Thanks. I will not use again. I did my proofread. Thanks.

Comment: Any help Please?